# Sharing data between jQuery methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could a variable be shared between two different jQuery methods (i.e. `init` and `someMethod`)?  I am doing so below using jQuery `data()`, however, expect there is a more efficient non-jQuery way of doing so.

```
(function( $ ){

    var methods = {
        init : function( options ) {
            return this.each(function(){
                $(this).data('myData',123);
            });
        },

        someMethod : function() {
            return $(this).each(function(){
                console.log($(this).data('myData'))
            })
        },
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin' );
        }    
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: Well, by using `data()` you're storing it in jQuery's cache. You could use your own caching object.

Comment: @Johan  How could I cache it myself?  Since I am using `each` over each matched element, I will have potentially multiple instances.

Comment: jQuery solves unique cahche keys by doing `$.cache[HTMLElement[$.expando]]`. You would obviously need to do something similar. But what's the problem using the built-in method? Performance issues? Don't reinvent the wheel, IMO.

Comment: `$.fn.myPlugin.cache = {}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object that will stores everything and set this object to the element data, so you won't need to create it twice for the same element.

```
;(function($, undefined){
    "use strict"; // Put this instruction to avoid some javascript quirks mode...

    var defaults = {
        myData: undefined,
        init: _init,
        someMethod: _someMethod
    }

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(method) {
        var response = this;
        this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var mp = $this.data('plugin_myplugin');

            if (!mp)
                $this.data('plugin_myplugin', new MyPlugin($this, method));
            else if (typeof method === 'string' && method.length > 0)
                response = mp[method].apply(mp, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            else
                $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin' );
        });

        return response;
    };
    $.fn.MyPlugin = function() {
        return $(this).data('plugin_myplugin');
    };

    function MyPlugin($element, options) {
        this.$element = $element;
        $.extend(true, this, $.fn.MyPlugin.defaults, $element.data(), options);

        this.init();
    }
    $.fn.MyPlugin.defaults = defaults;

    function _init() {
        this.myData = 123;
    }

    function _someMethod() {
        console.log(this.myData);
    }
}(jQuery));
```

There are a couple important things here:

- To override the defaults, you can simply do `$.extend($.fn.MyPlugin.defaults, {someMethod: function() {alert(123);}});`
- Any instance can override some methods, e.g.:
  `<div id="div-test" data-some-value="123456">`

  ```
  $('#div-test').myPlugin({
      someOtherValue: "asd",
      someMethod: function() {alert(123); return "asdfgh"; }
  });
  var mp = $('#div-test').MyPlugin();
  console.log(mp.someValue); // prints 123456
  console.log(mp.someOtherValue); // prints "asd"
  console.log(mp.someMethod); // prints that function up there.
  ```
- I put the undefined as one of the parameter, but I didn't define any arguments at the bottom, that is because some old browser allows the undefined to be changed, so, we are forcing the undefined.